# fabric8 kubernetes client exception

Tags: exception, kubernetes, fabric8

I am using the fabric8 library to create replication controllers on the kubernetes cluster. When I create areplication controller with the name `rc-UUID.toString()`;

It errors aout with the following message 
`ReplicationController is forbidden`. What does this indicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that the problem is the name. 
Names like: rc-fa75ddfd-bea7-45b5-8d2f-ed806652b461 are valid.

Usually the message forbidden appears in one of the following cases:

i) http status code 401
ii) https status code 404

Error (i) appears when you are connecting to a remote Kubernetes Environment and can be solved by login in. Try **kubectl login** or **oc login**.

Error (ii) appears when the client is instantiated from within Kubernetes and the service account hasn't been properly configured.

Either way, I'd strongly encourage you to upgrade to a more recent version of the cabernets client, which has more meaningful error messages.

If none of my suggestion solves your issue, please attach the full output.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you I had figured out that there was an error creating a namespace and hadnt caught the exception. Hence the controller wasnt created which Iw as trying to access